# React setState not working

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, typeerror, setstate

I have the following constructor and function in a react component that I've created.

```
constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
        error: false
    }
}

handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    const email = this.refs.email.value
    const password = this.refs.password.value
    const self = this

    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(
        function(result) {
            const location = self.props.location
            if (location.state && location.state.nextPathname) {
                self.context.router.replace(location.state.nextPathname)
            } else {
                self.context.router.replace("/home")
            }
            // User signed in!
            console.log("User signed in!")
    }).catch(function(error) {
        this.setState({error: error}) // Error points to this line
    })
}
```

I keep getting the following error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

Can anyone help my identify the problem?

Comment: do you need to use `refs` to get the values? If the component is an `input` element you could use the `onChange` event and update a variable with the value.

Comment: Is there a benefit to using that over `refs`?

Comment: Refs should be a last resort when you can't do the same with events, state or props according to the documentation. Also shallow rendering doesn't work when unit testing with them.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that, I'll look into changing that for better practices, thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the following code, you use 'this', when you should be using 'self'

```
catch(function(error) {
    this.setState({error: error}) // Error points to this line
})
```

should be

```
catch(function(error) {
    self.setState({error: error}) // Error points to this line
})
```

Comment: You could also use an arrow function and then `this` would inherit the lexical scope of `handleSubmit`

Comment: Thanks, that worked!  I also had to user `error: error.message` but that's out of the scope of my question

Comment: @ken4z How would I accomplish that?

Comment: `catch((error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }))`. You will have to setup something to transpile the code though because not all browsers support that feature yet.  Babel is a popular choice.  Given that you are asking the question though I'd suggest going with the answer above as it doesn't require that build step.

Comment: Ah ok. Sorry more the poor assumption! Good luck